# How do I get the amount paid, reference number, firstname lastname and date from the given string

Tags: java, regex, extract

New balance is TZS 58,000. You have received 53,000 from FIRSTNAME LASTNAME, 0712349009. 03/12/2013 11:21 AM, Reference no. PP131203.1121.A01676. Pay your bills with Tigo Pesa for free. Tigo Pesa tunarahisisha Maisha.

I have tried to use split() but I am afraid the details and positions may change

Expected output, I want the to assign what I found from the message to the variables ie

```
`newBalance=58,000` 
`amountReceived=53,000` 
`fullName=FIRSTNAME LASTNAME` 
`fromNumber0712349009 `
`dateReceived=03/12/2013 11:21 AM` 
`referenceNumber=PP131203.1121.A01676`
```

So that I can add these values to the database etc.

Here is what I have tried.

```
String message[] = msg.split(" "); 
String amount = message[4]; 
String fullname = message[10]+" "+message[11]; 
String from = message[12]; 
String datetime = message[13]+" "+message[14]+" "+message[15]; 
String ref_number = message[18];
```

Comment: If the format is not going to stay the same then there is nothing to be done. Also, it is generally expected that you show your attempt at coding a solution in your question.

Comment: Here is what I have tried 
`String message[] = msg.split(" ");`
`String amount = message[4];`
`String fullname = message[10]+" "+message[11];`
`String from = message[12];`
`String datetime = message[13]+" "+message[14]+" "+message[15];`
`String ref_number = message[18];`
@thatidiotguy

Comment: @Gpak: I have updated the question with details from your comment. It is always better to post information like what you have tried in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As previously stated, you must make some assumptions about the formatting, else you cannot extract data.

The following extracts segments into numbered capturing groups
1.  Amount owed (Balance)
2.  Amount paid (Received)
3.  Firstname Lastname (after "from" and before comma)
4.  Date (string with format of digit(s)/digit(s)/digit(s))
5.  Reference Number (string following Reference No. and ending with a dot

If some of those assumptions can vary, the regex will need to be edited:

```
"balance is \\D+([\\d,]+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*?([\\d,]+(?:\\.\\d+)?).*?from\\s+([^,]+).*?\\b(\\d+/\\d+/\\d+)\\b.*?Reference no.\\s+(\\S+?)\\.\\s"
```

You should set the options for case insensitive and Dot matches line breaks

Answer (score 1):

```
(?i)((?<=(from\s))[a-z]+\s[a-z]+|(?<=(received\s))[0-9]+\,?[0-9]+|(?<=\.\s)\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}\s[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}(\s(am)|\s(pm))?)
```

May look long and confusing but from:

```
New balance is TZS 58,000. You have received 53,000 from FIRSTNAME LASTNAME, 0712349009. 03/12/2013 11:21 AM, Reference no. PP131203.1121.A01676. Pay your bills with Tigo Pesa for free. Tigo Pesa tunarahisisha Maisha.
```

This will match:

```
58,000
FIRSTNAME LASTNAME
03/12/2013 11:21 AM
```

***EXPLANATION:***

So pretty much we can split the regex into three pieces as it is formatted like this `(some regex|some regex|some regex)` `|=OR`

Before we begin `(?i)` just means that any Alphabetic matching will be case insensitive meaning `[a-z]` will match capitals and lowercase letters.

***Piece 1:***

```
(?<=(from\s))[a-z]+\s[a-z]+
```

This Is looking for two words following a `from` which in this case will be the `first name and last name`

I suggest researching `Lookaheads` and `Lookbehinds` to understand this more clearly.

***Piece 2:***

```
(?<=(received\s))[0-9]+\,?[0-9]+
```

This is matching some numbers with an optional comma in. `?` after a character means previous character is optional.

***Piece 3: The more confusing***

```
(?<=\.\s)\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}\s[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}(\s(am)|\s(pm))?
```

First off date:

```
(?<=\.\s)\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{2,4}\s
```

This is match after a full stop `1 or two numbers` then a `/` the `\` is escaping the `/`. Then doing the same again matching `1 or 2 numbers` the another slash and then mathcing `2 or 4 numbers` for the year. Then a space. Next we have the time:

```
[0-9]{1,2}\:[0-9]{1,2}(\s(am)|\s(pm))?
```

Here we are matching `1 or 2 numbers` then a `:` being escaped by a `\` then `1 or 2 numbers` again then we are matching a space and either `am, pm or neither` case doesn't matter. Hope this helps!:-)